# Spring Security: Local profile is token based but Dev profile defaults to username password

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I want to implement token-based authentication. I am able to do it by adding filters. This seems to work in `local` profile only, but when I go to `dev` profile I get defaulted to `Using generated security password: xxx` , and the logs also do not register filters in `dev` profile like they do for `local` profile.

`application-local.yml` :

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

# Configuration used to validate header
auth:
    userid: gibberish213 # header key: header value
```

`application-dev.yml` :

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  datasource: 
   # Datasource related configs
  application:
    name: token-auth

# Configuration used to validate 
auth:
    userid: gibberish213 # header key: header value
```

I have an empty SpringSecurityInitializer class, would I need to add some config in that class:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have @Profile("local") annotation at top of your filter beans. If you do, they only work at the specified profile.